# Applications of Derivatives problem

Tags: functions, derivatives

$$f(x) = x^3 + ax^2 + bx + 5\sin^2x $$
is an increasing function on the set $R$. Then $a$ and $b$ satisfy:

1. $a^2 - 3b - 15 > 0$
2. $a^2 - 3b + 15 > 0$
3. $a^2 - 3b + 15 < 0$
4. $ a> 0$ and $b > 0$

I know I have to differentiate the function but I am unable to solve the equation due to the $\sin^2x$ term I get after differentiating.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$f'(x)=3x^2+2ax+b+10\sin x\cos x=3x^2+2ax+b+5\sin (2x)$$
In order to have $f$ increasing we need $f'(x)>0$ for all real number $x$. It is reached if 
$$3x^2+2ax+b-5>0\qquad\text{for all }x\in\mathbb{R}\qquad\text{since }\sin(2x)\ge-1$$
So the discriminant of the quadratic polynomial must be negative:
$$(2a)^2-4(3)(b-5)<0\quad\iff\quad4a^2-12b+60<0\quad\iff\quad a^2-3b+15<0$$