# If $f(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+5\sin^2x$ is a strictly increasing function on the set of real numbers then $a$ and $b$ must satisfy the relation

Tags: calculus

If $f(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+5\sin^2x$ is a strictly increasing function on the set of real numbers then $a$ and $b$ must satisfy the relation
$(A)a^2-3b+15\leq0$
$(B)a^2-3b+20\leq0$
$(C)a^2-3b+25\leq0$
$(D)a^2-3b+30\leq0$

---

Since $f(x)=x^3+ax^2+bx+5\sin^2x$ is a strictly increasing function.
So $f'(x)=3x^2+2ax+b+5\sin2x>0$
I am stuck here.

Comment: Note that -1 <= sin 2x <= 1 .

Comment: The quadratic equation $ a x^2 + b x + c = 0 $ has no solution if $ b^2 - 4 a c < 0 $

Comment: Very close to http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1702035/applications-of-derivatives-problem/1702061#1702061

Comment: Did you try $b>a$ then $f(b)>f(a)$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since 
\begin{align*}
3x^2+2ax+b+5\sin2x \geq 3x^2+2ax+b-5.
\end{align*}
Consider the quadratic expression $3x^2+2ax+b-5$. For this to be strictly positive, the discriminant should be $\leq 0$. Thus
\begin{align*}
4a^2-12(b-5) & \leq 0\\
a^2-3b+15 & \leq 0.
\end{align*}

Comment: So that's a sufficient condition, but since OP's question was "$a$ en $b$ *must* satisfy the relation", is it also necessary? It is the weakest of the given possible choices, of course, but from a mathematical point of view, this still needs some clarifying.